# Do I need to create a new brand for a new language with customized XML resource file?

Tags: docusignapi

We want to be able to use both English and Spanish for Docusign flow, depending on what the user chose, and right now we only have brands created for English, with a few changes to both email and signing XML resource files in Docusign. Those changes are not applied if I use the same brand with Spanish language: the Docusign experience is translated but the default resource file settings are used.
I see a way to download the Spanish version of the resource file but then there is just one upload button and I don't want to replace English one with Spanish, I want to have both.
Do I need to create a new brand for a new language? Couldn't find anything about it in Docusign docs...

Answer (score 0):

One Brand resource file can contain multiple languages. See the [docs](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=docusign-signing-resource-file-guide&topicId=docusign-signing-resource-file-guide.pdf&_LANG=enus) -- see page 11.